# How to pass parameter from method to hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hql

I'm unable to pass the method parameter to the hibernate query's named parameter,

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Cinema cin set cin = #{cinema} where cin.id = #{cinema.id}")
    Cinema updateCinema(@Param("cinema") Cinema cinema);
```

Getting the following error,

```
 "Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '#' "
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: use :cinema insteaf of #{cinema}

Answer (score 0):

Within a query annotation you can use `:<parameter>` (e.g. `:cinema`) to reference a parameter.

It looks like you simply want to update a specific entity. Is there any reason why you not simply use `entityManager.merge(cinema)`?

Since you are using Spring-boot you might also be using Spring data. In this case `cinemaRepsotory.save(cinema)` should work too.

Comment: So, query needs to have this view? @Query("update Cinema cin set cin = :cinema where cin.id = :cinema.id")

Comment: if `id` is your primary key the where clause would look like this: `where cin = :cinema`. I don't know if `cin = :cinema` works. But you should use the entityManager for this kind of operation. There is no need to write the query yourself if you only want to update an entity with a given primary key.